# Unable to create Dataframe from Nested Multiplayer XML

Tags: xml, dataframe

I have an XML like this

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<document>
  <employee>
    <name>
      <lastname>Kelly</lastname>
      <firstname>Grace</firstname>
    </name>
    <hiredate>October 15, 2005</hiredate>
    <projects>
      <project>
        <product>Printer</product>
        <id>111</id>
        <price>$111.00</price>
      </project>
      <project>
        <product>Laptop</product>
        <id>222</id>
        <price>$989.00</price>
      </project>
    </projects> 
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name>
      <lastname>Grant</lastname>
      <firstname>Cary</firstname>
    </name>
    <hiredate>October 20, 2005</hiredate>
    <projects>
      <project>
        <product>Desktop</product>
        <id>333</id>
        <price>$2995.00</price>
      </project>
      <project>
        <product>Scanner</product>
        <id>444</id>
        <price>$200.00</price>
      </project>
    </projects> 
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name>
      <lastname>Gable</lastname>
      <firstname>Clark</firstname>
    </name>
    <hiredate>October 25, 2005</hiredate>
    <projects>
      <project>
        <product>Keyboard</product>
        <id>555</id>
        <price>$129.00</price>
      </project>
      <project>
        <product>Mouse</product>
        <id>666</id>
        <price>$25.00</price>
      </project>
    </projects> 
  </employee>
</document>
```

I am trying to get an output like following

```
lastname    firstname   hiredate            product     id      price
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Kelly       Grace       October 15, 2005    Printer     111     $111.00
Kelly       Grace       October 15, 2005    Laptop      222     $989.00
Grant       Cary        October 20, 2005    Desktop     333     $2995.00
Grant       Cary        October 20, 2005    Scanner     444     $200.00
Gable       Clark       October 25, 2005    Keyboard    555     $129.00
Gable       Clark       October 25, 2005    Mouse       666     $25.00
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/557Yy.png)

I am able to get 6 lists for the 6 elements using following but unable to get the desired output

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import pandas as pd
firstname=[]
lastname=[]
hiredate=[]
product=[]
id=[]
price=[]

tree=et.parse('D:\\xmlTocsv\\employee.xml')
root=tree.getroot()
        
for child in root:
    if child.tag == "employee":
        for step_child in child:
            if step_child.tag == "name":
                firstname.append(step_child.find('firstname').text)
                lastname.append(step_child.find('lastname').text)
            elif step_child.tag == "hiredate":
                hiredate.append(step_child.text)
            elif step_child.tag == "projects":
                for step_child2 in step_child:
                    if step_child2.tag == "project":
                        product.append(step_child2.find('product').text)
                        id.append(step_child2.find('id').text)
                        price.append(step_child2.find('price').text)
                        
#df = pd.DataFrame({'lastname': lastname, 'firstname': firstname, 'hiredate': hiredate, 'product': product, 'id': id, 'price': price})
#print(df)
```

I tried with 'iter' as well but due to nested structure (parent-child relation) could not get the required result. Also the 'project' element can appear any number of times 2-3 times etc for same name element

Please Help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas_read_xml as pdx
df = pdx.read_xml("example.xml", ['lastname', 'firstname', 'thiredate', 'product','id',' price'])
df.head()
```